# Angular 4: Material dialog: how do we know the component is initialised or not?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Im opening the dialog by this

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DynamicComponent, options);
```

How do we know when the DynamicComponent is initialised and rendered in Dialog? I just want to execute few things after dialog renders DynamicComponent.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the **[api](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)** you can subscribe to `afterOpen`:

so mark the following where you are declaring

```ts
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DynamicComponent, options);
dialogRef.afterOpen().subscribe(() => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)